# Rust: is there a way to know that an arg is of some generic type, without caring about its inner type?

Tags: generics, rust

I know that I can use the `TypeId` to find out if an arg is of some specific type:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

fn is_string<T: ?Sized + Any>(_s: &T) -> bool {
    TypeId::of::<String>() == TypeId::of::<T>()
}
```

but is there a way to know that an arg is of some generic type, without caring about the inner type?

For exapmle, can I somehow find out if an arg is a Vec<_>, without caring for the inner type?

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

fn is_vec<T: ?Sized + Any>(_s: &T) -> bool {
    TypeId::of::<Vec<_>>() == TypeId::of::<T>() // This fails with error[E0282]: type annotations needed
}
```

I would like to know if this is possible in *any* way in Rust, not only using TypeId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a generalizable way to do this in stable rust, although it won't let you check if a `dyn Any` is a `Vec<_>`. instead, what I did was create a super trait of any with an impl for both `Vec<T>` and `dyn Any`. Code:

```rust
trait MyAny:Any{
    fn get_container(&self)->Container;
} 

impl<T:Any> MyAny for Vec<T>{
    fn get_container(&self)->Container{
        Vector
    }
}
impl MyAny for dyn Any{
    fn get_container(&self)->Container{
        Any
    }
}
```

with container being an enum defined as

```
#[derive(Clone,Copy,PartialEq,Eq)]
#[non_exhaustive]
enum Container{
    Vector,
    Any,
}
```

from there, defining an `is_vec` function is easy:

```rust
fn is_vec<T:MyAny + ?Sized>(s:&T)->bool{
    s.get_container() == Vector
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1512fcada7388fa9fa46e2e36c79277)

Comment: Thanks! This is much better than something like parsing the [type_name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, no way to do this in stable Rust comes to my mind.

However, as you ask for *any* way, [here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51d585ec7d66144dfacdeb198a76bdb5) a thing using specialization on nightly rust:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait TIsVector {
    fn is_vector(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> TIsVector for T {
    default fn is_vector(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

impl<T> TIsVector for Vec<T> {
    default fn is_vector(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(1usize.is_vector());
    dbg!(true.is_vector());
    dbg!("sdf".is_vector());
    dbg!(vec![1,2,3].is_vector());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I accepted the answer that can work with the stable channel.